# Using socket.io for the first time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make an web app that use Javascript and Node.js. I need to make a call from Javascript to Node.js because I must be able to pass params and I can't have them until an leaflet event is pass. I am trying to use Socket.io to pass thoses params but I can't make it to work. here is my test code that don't work. Can somebody help me figure out why it is not working?

ps. I am running on a personnal php and Node.js server.

Client-side :

```
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('localhost');
        socket.on('news', function (data){
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Server-side :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});

   socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
      console.log(data); 
   });
});
```

Error from browser : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu4OD.png)

Comment: did you try changing the port? apache uses that port

Comment: Please include the error as text, not as an image. Also, search the web for the error text, as it's likely been answered before.

Comment: I just try it and no change (I try port 8000)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to use, I leave you a page where it shows you step by step how to use the framework.

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

And its corresponding repo where it shows how to use the example.

https://github.com/socketio/chat-example

Basically you have to do.

```
git clone https://github.com/socketio/chat-example.git

npm install

npm start
```

I would change the index.js file to understand where messages go

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    // This is the additional line
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

If you have a cors error, add into index.js file.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: I did start by trying to change my line require at the start of my server-side file to the ones you wrote and it have help I think because the error change. Now my browser say net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE

Comment: Sorry to hear that, the first error of cors that you had is solved by adding the lines in my response.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a cross origin request error.

Have a look into CORS middleware for express.

Essentially, you're sending a request from a different domain without express knowing that the other domain is permitted access to your server, so it refuses access.

What you need in essence is an access-control header on the request.